Setup connection between Jenkins and Tricentis Test Automation
As part of the test environment creation our project wants to integrate Jenkins Server with TTA. The problem is that this tool does not have a Tosca CI Client, which is required to create a pipeline according to Tricentis specifications. The CI Client is part of the more advanced Tosca tool, which my project does not have a license for.
So the question is whether it is possible to integrate TTA with Jenkins, and if so, how?
Thanks in advance for any answer
